# IntelliJ IDEA compilation fails with "java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address" on macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, java-11

I get this error note no matter what program Im trying to run

> Abnormal build process termination: nice -n 10
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-19.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
>
> ...
>
> Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:60033; reason: Can't assign requested
> address: /127.0.0.1:60033
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Can't
> assign requested address: /127.0.0.1:60033 Caused by:
> java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:483)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:472)

tried installing other different jdks with no success:(

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the complete logs attached.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-312754/JDK-not-working-in-intellij-on-macos

Comment: The actual error is "java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address", see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332407/how-to-change-ifconfig-lo0 for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332407/how-to-change-ifconfig-lo0) for the solution.

This command should help:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with a Hello World Kotlin program I was trying to execute on a fresh-downloaded IntelliJ IDEA CE (on MacOs).

The `alias` command did not help, but if I can fix it by changing the run command to have the following JVM arg:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```